# exit splash screen on pressing back

Tags: android, exit, splash-screen, back-button

on pressing "BACK" in the splash screen,the app exits and restarts after sometime.I don't want the app to be restarted once it exits from the splash screen.i tried

```
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
{
    Start.this.finish();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 

}
```

this but its not working.

Comment: [See this post](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/) for an explanation of why it is doing that, and a way to correct it. Also I would strongly advise against having a splash screen in your application if you do not have some work that needs to be done before you can run. Forcing your users to wait for some seconds for no reason whenever they use your app will do nothing but annoy them.

Answer (score 0):

From the SplashScreen if you have created another thread to Start your next Activity after some time mean, you have to stop that too.

Comment: i gave
                                                    splashTread.stop();
     after start.this.finish();                                           the thread couldn't be stopped because of the time interval specification.Though "STOP" is specified,the thread is restarting

Comment: try AsyncTask , you can use cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) method which Attempts to cancel execution of Async task